# std::is_nothrow_constructible when constructor is inherited

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider following two examples:

```
struct A {
    A () noexcept = default;
};

struct B : A {
    B () noexcept = default;

    template <typename T>
    B (T) noexcept {}
};

struct C : A {
    using A::A;

    template <typename T>
    C (T) noexcept {} 
};
```

and usage:

```
std::cout << std::is_nothrow_constructible<B>::value << std::endl; // (X)
std::cout << std::is_nothrow_constructible<B, int>::value << std::endl;

std::cout << std::is_nothrow_constructible<C>::value << std::endl; // (Y)
std::cout << std::is_nothrow_constructible<C, int>::value << std::endl;
```

Output is:

```
1
1
0
1
```

Compiler used: GCC 4.8.1.

So, If I write explicitly default `B` constructor, `(X)` produces 1, on the other hand if default `C` constructor is available because of the inheritance, `(Y)` produces 0. Why is that?

**Does it mean that inherited constructors are not taken into account when `is_nothrow_constructible` trait is used?**

Comment: It means that the compiler-supplied constructor for `C` is not necessarily `noexcept`.   Consider what would happen, for example, if `C` had a member which could throw during its construction.

Comment: `std::is_constructible<C>::value` is actually also `false`.

Comment: It seems the problem here is not the inheriting `noexcept` but rather the templated constructor that hides the inherited ones (remove the templated constructor, and the `std::is_nothrow_constructible<C>::value` is `true`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that the templated constructor hides the inherited constructor. From §12.9/4:

> A constructor so declared [...]. It is deleted if the corresponding constructor in X is deleted (8.4.3) or if a defaulted default constructor (12.1) would be deleted, [...].

The following compiles without problem:

```
struct C: A {
    using A::A;
};
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_constructible<C>{}, "");
```

Comment: You don't even need the using declaration if `A` only contains a default c'tor, since default constructors aren't subject to inheritance. The compiler will still synthesize a default `c'tor` here, and it will be `noexcept` because `A::A` is `noexcept`.

Comment: @StoryTeller true, I just wanted to show that removing the templated constructor solves the problem which is why I left the `using` declaration.

Comment: @Holt That's cool, if I would know the answer my question would be: "How to achieve correct behavior with overloaded templated constructor, because I need it to be there". Anyway thanks for your effort.